# How can I edit files like frontend/.../category/view.phtml?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, module, product-list, category-view

I have been trying to edit some files from the frontend folder.
On this folder I have the following folders: 
base, default, rwd and typologancee.

I have to create a specific filter which is going to be used on specific categories.
I have thought in developing this one to append the code on 
category/view.phtml and products/list.phtml 
even though I also have thought in doing it by developing a module.

I do not know which one is the correct way but my real doubt is how to edit these files, because I have done it and the page continues showing the old code.
I edited every category/view.phtml files from every frontend subfolder 
but there are no results.

I deleted the cache folder, reindex some data, deleted cache and cookies from chrome, as well as giving permissions to these files but nothing is happening.
I would like some urgent support because I can not do any test.

**EDIT 1:
I have achieved modify the file with results, but I am using visual studio code, and I did not modifying the correct file because when I find by word, some folders are being hidden when search and these folders have a diffent colour and I have not idea about why is happening this.
[image: You can see the base folder with light gray...]
I only have results if I modify the file under base folder, but I have read that this is a bad practice, so, what should I do?
The template typologancee is active, but when I modify their files nothing happens.
Thanks.

[image: structure theme]

[image: structure base]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you have to do modification in above files for product detail page and product detail page.and yes its a bad practices to modify base folder file what you can do is place those file with same folder structure in you current theme directory.Make sure you place file on correct location else any modification won't be visible on front-end.

You are able to see changes on frontend when u change in base file because that's how magento work it work on fallback concept which means if you already overrides the files in your custom theme with proper directory structure then magento first read that file if magento won't find file there then it goes to base folder and execute that file.

Hope this information helps.

Comment: Khandelwai Thanks for your answer. I have an image of base structure and another of theme structure. The file which I want to modify has the same structure but base have more folders than theme even though the differences are for other files, then, if I want to see changes on frontend, all the folder should be exactly like base? base/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml and theme/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml are equals but for example on the category base folder there is a subfolder widget and in theme folder not, can this be the problem here?

Comment: Hey thanks for response,Yes we will only put those files in our custom theme which we want to customise i know there are many files in base folder but we only override those files in our custom theme which we want to modify and that file folder structure should be Exact for example:

we have file in Base like: A/B/C/D/YourFile

in custom theme it should be
A/B/C/D/YourFile

Comment: Khandewal hi again, you can see that view.phtml in the 2 images that I uploaded in my question and both have the same structure but only change the page if I modify the base. Do you think about other option? Because my files have the same folder structure. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey Are you trying to change product detail page? if it is then that view.phtml should be in catalog/product/view.phtml.

Comment: Khandelwai no, I am not trying to modify product view. I am modifying category view. If you have seen my images, you would have seen that the route of base/.../category/view.phtml and theme/.../category/view.phtml is the same but modifying the file from de theme route have no effects.